# Kivy pass variables to function in class

Tags: python, function, class, kivy

I play around with Kivy and have build some buttons with:

```
    for i in range(30):
        self.user = str(i)
        self.btn = Button(text=self.user, size_hint_y=None, height=40)
        self.btn.bind(on_press=self.auth(self.user))
        self.layout.add_widget(self.btn)
```

these buttons call auth:

```
def auth(mytext,instance):
    print "auth called"
    popup = Popup(title="success",
        content=Label(text=mytext),
        size=(100, 100),
        size_hint=(0.3, 0.3),
        auto_dismiss=False)
    popup.open()
```

Why I don't get passed the self.user containing string's to the auth function mytext variabe?

I get a `AssertionError: None is not callable`.

Answer (score 0):

instance containing all content of the pressed button.

```
for i in range(30):
    self.user = str(i)
    self.btn = Button(text=self.user, size_hint_y=None, height=40)
    self.btn.bind(on_press=self.auth)
    self.layout.add_widget(self.btn)
```

and

```
def auth(self, instance):
    print "auth called"
    popup = Popup(title="success",
        content=Label(content=Label(text='The button <%s> is being pressed' % instance.text),
        size=(100, 100),
        size_hint=(0.3, 0.3),
        auto_dismiss=False)
    popup.open()
```

its also possible to give the buttons a id like

```
self.btn = Button(text="Test User", size_hint_y=None, height=40, id=self.user)
```

and and get the id with `instance.id`

```
content=Label(content=Label(text='The button <%s> is being pressed' % instance.id)
```